# Cannot connect to a replica set using seeds localhost:27017

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid 1.4.12 and I have a mongos running local.This mongos points to a few replica sets in sharding mode.

My mongoid.yml looks like this:

```
production: &production
  database: db_name
  hosts:
    - - localhost
      - 27017
  read_secondary: true
```

however i am getting this error:

> Cannot connect to a replica set using seeds localhost:27017

Why? how it should be the proper configuration then?

I am afraid that if i change to

> host: locahost

It wont read from my secondary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So my final config was:

```
production: &production
  database: db_name
  host: localhost
  slave_ok: true
```

and it works just fine reading from secondary through my localhost mongos .

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure your mongos is running on port 27017 - connect to it with the mongo shell.  Since you are using the default port, this is as simple as running the `mongo` executable with no arguments (it defaults to connecting on localhost:27017).

If that does not connect, then mongos is likely not running, and that is your problem.  If it is running and you can connect, then try this in your yml file instead:

```
hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

Leave off the read_secondary piece to confirm the connection works.  Then try this rather than read_secondary (see here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1368):

```
options:
    read: :secondary
```

Comment: getting this error, when i tried to add hosts in the config: undefined method `map' for "localhost:27017":String